# How to view the stream generated from mkvserver via ffplay?

Tags: ffmpeg, live-streaming, mkv

I want to live stream from one source(ffmpeg) to multiple clients for which I'm using [mkvserver](https://github.com/klaxa/mkvserver_mk2).
I'm able to live stream a webcam from [ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/)(client) to [mkvserver](https://github.com/klaxa/mkvserver_mk2)(server) as follows:

**On Server :**

```
nc -l <port-number> | ./server
```

**On Client :**

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -framerate 30 -i 0 -b 900k -f matroska -r 20 tcp://<ip-address>:<port-number>
```

To view the genereted steam on server, I used the `ffplay` as:

```
ffplay tcp://<ip-address>:<port>
```

but I got the `Connection timed out error`. Please suggest a way to view the generated stream on the server via `ffplay`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me recap for clarification.

You are streaming from the client with ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -framerate 30 -i 0 -b 900k -f matroska -r 20 tcp://<ip-address>:<port-number>
```

to the server which listen with NetCat in some port over TCP.

```
nc -l <port-number>
```

You are piping the NetCat outPut (client steam) to Matroska Server Mk2 (./server) which serve the streaming in real-time [over **http** on all interfaces on port **8080**](https://github.com/klaxa/mkvserver_mk2/blob/master/Readme.md).

```
nc -l <port-number> | ./server
```

So I think that ffplay should connect through http in port 8080 to view the output of Matroska Server Mk2 (./server).

```
ffplay http://ip-address:8080
```

Comment: This is perfectly working. I got `tcp` confused for `http` when it should be `http` on the receiving end. Thanks~